# Terrible Memory Killing on Xcode6-beta4 in OS X

Tags: macos, memory, interface-builder, xcode6

It's really bad, I won't believe this!!!
My Macbook Air mid 2013 has updated to OS X, and I installed Xcode6-beta4.
As long as I run my app on simulator, my memory will be eaten so far as 3GB, and even more!
[image]

Does anyone happen to this?

Comment: It's a beta. File a radar and perhaps they will fix it. Truth be told though, that kind of memory usage from Xcode is not unusual for me (even in non-betas).

Comment: @vcsjones My OS X has upgraded to Preview 4 step by step. And Memory killing disappeared.